# How do I see how many votes I have earned till date?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, vote-count

We can already see a breakup of up or down votes that we earned in all but where's the **total** count that we earned?

Comment: _We can already see a breakup of up or down votes that we earned in all_ __Where?__ If you're talking about the numbers shown in your profile page, it is the number of votes you've given out.

Comment: No, I mean, the votes you see alongside your answers or comments. Those are the votes you scored/earned and which others have given you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's the number on the first line of this site:

https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: But if I count my up votes and down votes, it comes to 20 in all. The above link shows 35. But I haven't earned 35 votes.

Comment: @Mamta Dalal: The number of up/down-votes on your user profile is the amount of votes *you* have cast yourself, not received

Comment: No Tobias, I didnt mean that number. I was referring to the votes you see alongside your answers or comments in your user profile page. Those are the votes *you* scored/earned and which others have given you for your answers.